Styled Components DefaultTheme Disallow Additional Properties
I am using styled-components and have defined a theme type in a root-level .d.ts file as so:
import "styled-components";
import { CSSProperties } from 'react';

type RequiredCSSProperties = Required<CSSProperties>;

declare module "styled-components" {
    export interface DefaultTheme {
        backgroundColor: RequiredCSSProperties["backgroundColor"],
        // Other properties...
    }
}

This works mostly as expected, but if I were to misspell a property name, it infers the type any instead of giving an error like I expect:
styled.div`
    background-color: ${
        ({theme}) => theme.nonExistentProperty // Inferred as "any"
    };
`;

I do not want this, as such misspelled properties will never be present in the Theme implementation, so such a mistake should be caught as such. The any inference comes from the default implementation in styled-components, I believe, as this new interface uses declaration merging.
I have attempted to override the string type like so with no effect:
export interface DefaultTheme {
    // Try to prevent additional properties from being accessed
    [key: string]: never;
    
    backgroundColor: RequiredCSSProperties["backgroundColor"],
    // Other properties...
}

I'm not sure how else to approach this issue.
